# Problem when inserting seperators to listview-items

Tags: java, android, listview

i am making some listview. Now I inserted some little pictures to seperate the columns. ( Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtWj5.png ) My problem is here, they should be at the same point of the display, but as you see they aren't. the item's seperator don't fit exactly..my layouts:
for the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0">
     <TableRow>
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="@string/id"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
     <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="14" 
        android:text="@string/amount"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="@string/unit"
        android:gravity="center"/>
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and the layout for the single items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:stretchColumns="0">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lId"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="right"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:gravity="left"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lamount"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:gravity="right"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lunit"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

any solutions on how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use fixed widths for the columns to make everything line up correctly.

**Edit:**

Programmatically...

```
// Grab the layout
LayoutParams l = ((View)findViewById(R.id.xxx)).getLayoutParams();

// Manipulate height/width
// ...

// Set the new values
((View)findViewById(R.id.xxx)).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(...));
```

Comment: are you sure that there is no other way to get some columns-seperator?

Comment: Yes, for the columns to line up you need fixed widths. You _could_ alter these widths programatically; however, each element has to have the same column widths to look right.

Comment: I guess that will result in some coding action... i bet there is some method to get the current screen size and then i can set the view_widths with some calculating.... 
i just thought there would be some smoother way :/

Comment: The problem is that various screen sizes and content within the columns will force your layouts to differ in width if you don't use fixed sizes. There's no way around that.

Comment: ok I am now into that.... is there something like using a constructor LinearLayout l = getLayout(R.id.mainlinearlayout);  and then l.getHeight() ? ((the constructor doesn't work)

Comment: this method doesn't work somehow. it's the wrong type.. you get the type LayoutParams back and not LinearLayout.
i tried something i found: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

but this giives me a nullpointerexception. lolz